# CostaRico/yii2-images, убрать плейсхолдер

Tags: yii2, изображения, модули, placeholder

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать плейсхолдер в этом модуле https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images, может кто сталкивался с этим ?
Вот если нет изображения, то и не выводить ничего. http://joxi.ru/Vm6z3w9CW97WmZ.
Пробовал закомментировать вот эту строку в конфиге, но тогда плывет верстка и появляется ошибка Call to a member function getUrl() on null, `'placeHolderPath' => '@webroot/images/placeHolder.png'`.
Переопределял класс ImageBehave, закомментировав там упоминания о плейсхолдере, тоже плывет верстка, но ошибки нет. http://joxi.ru/n2YB0EZU194pA6 , а элементы должны рядом стоять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Верстка плыла из-за моего косяка. А убрать плейсхолдер получилось переопределив ImageBehave и заменив в функциях getImages(), getImage(), getImageByName($name), `return null;` вместо `[$this->getModule()->getPlaceHolder()];`

```
if(!$imageRecords){ 
       return null; // [$this->getModule()->getPlaceHolder()]; }
```

И еще если выводить все картинки, то появляется ошибка. Поэтому надо делать проверку, если есть картинки, то выводим их, если нету - не выводим ничего.